# How to give Alert box OR focus on error occur through Unobtrusive Validation JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, unobtrusive-validation

I am using the [Unobtrusive Jquery](https://thewayofcode.wordpress.com/tag/unobtrusive-jquery-validation/) for ClientSideValidation,Which is working correctly,

**I want to do some enhancement if Possible....!!**

1. How could I show an **Alert Box** that "something is missing" in a
   Page?
2. How could I **focus** on the error TextBox, Checkbox or any 
       Other control?

Any suggestion would be Helpful...!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 2), you can use custom JavaScript code like this:

```
$("selector for error messages, e.g. class name")[0].scrollIntoView().focus();
OR
document.querySelector("same selector").scrollIntoView().focus();
```

First method scrolls the page to your element with error, second focuses on that element.

Comment: Isn't `scrollIntoView` native JavaScript not JQuery? So the first example should be `$()[0].scrollIntoView();`?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have one input box for email

```
<input type="text" name="" class="" id='emailId' placeholder="" />

document.getElementById("emailId").focus();
```

if you have more than one input box you can try like this

```
 var myIds = ['id1', 'id1', 'id1', 'id1', 'id1']
for (var i in myIds) { fuction doValidation(myIds[i]) {} }

function getId(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}
fuction doValidation(myIds[i]) {
    if (getId(myIds[i]).value == 'your error check') {
        getId(myIds[i].focus();
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have 1000 control in my Page..!!!, Want to do for all in a single hit

Comment: Ok. then you do like

Comment: var myIds = ['id1', 'id1', 'id1', 'id1', 'id1']

for (var i in myIds) {
    fuction doValidation(myIds[i]) {

    }
}

function getId(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}

fuction doValidation(myIds[i]) {
    if (getId(myIds[i]).value=='your error check'){
    getId(myIds[i].focus();
    return false
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input[type='submit']").click(
function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // Do not actually submit
    alert("You entered " + $("#your-name-id").val() + ", age " + $("#your-age-id").val());
});
```

Comment: unobtrusive js fire when We submit a Page.

Comment: You can check this example